# How to extract the DFS properties of a folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I would like extract the information from the DFS property tab of a folder using powershell.

[image: DFS properties tab]

Essentially I would like to traverse through a folder structure and recursively retrieve the dfs information for every folder that has it.

Comment: Do you have Server 2012 or Windows 8? If so you should have the cmdlets needed to get that information with ease. Check out [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/10/19/introducing-dfs-namespaces-windows-powershell-cmdlets.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Nah, I am working with Windows 7.

Comment: I don't have anything to test with, but this looks like it should work: http://dfscommands.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Powershell snippet that helped me with the same question:

```
(Get-DfsnRoot -Domain example.net).Path |
    % { (Get-DfsnFolder -Path (Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath "\*")).Path } |
        % { Get-DfsnFolderTarget -Path $_ | select Path, TargetPath } |
            sort Path |
                ft -autosize
```

Some remarks:

- It uses the cmdlets from the [DFSR module for Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dfsr/), which is available since/for Windows Server 2012 R2, I believe (you may need to install/enable it first).
- The trailing `\*` at the end of the *Get-DfsnFolder -Path* parameter is important! Without it, I got a “CimException”; I first tried a simple string concatenation, but that didn’t work, that’s why I use Join-Path.
- I was only interested in the target paths, so other DFS properties weren't taken into consideration in the code snippet above.

The output should look like this:

```
Path                             TargetPath
----                             ----------
\\example.net\Admin\AdminScripts \\FS101XY0123.example.net\SysAdmin$\AdminScripts
\\example.net\Admin\Setup        \\fs302az8901.example.net\SysAdmin$\Tools\Setup
\\example.net\Admin\Tools        \\fs202zz4567.example.net\SysAdmin$\Tools
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `dfsutil` command:

```
PS C:\> dfsutil client property state $DFSPath
```

Comment: Answers with a bit of explanation are often more useful.

Comment: I'd argue that this answer isn't really "using PowerShell" either.

Answer (score 0):

### Using WMI

If you have permission to query WMI, you can use the `Get-WmiObject` PowerShell cmdlet; you should be able to adapt this example:

```
$DfsProvider = "SERVER"
$DfsPath = "\\SOME\DFS\Path"

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $DfsProvider -Class Win32_DFSTarget `
  -Filter "SELECT ServerName,ShareName,LinkName FROM Win32_DFSTarget WHERE LinkName = '$DfsPath'"
```

- [Win32_DFSTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394129(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN